# scrapy crawl a website

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I'm using scrapy for crawling a website news but I'm getting error when i do this process the website have many news page and the url of the news is www.example.com/34223 i was trying to find a way for fixing this problem and her is my code the scrapy version is 1.4.0 and I'm using MACOS

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class Example(scrapy.Spider):
name = "example"
allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]
  rules = (
    #self.log('testing rules' + response.url)
      # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
      # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/*', ), deny=(' ', ))),

      # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
  )

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
     item = scrapy.Item()
      item['title'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/text()').extract()
      item['img_url'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/img').extract()
      item['description'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/text()').extract()
      return item
```

Comment: when i run the code i get this error ERROR: Spider error processing (referer: None)

Comment: Change `allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.com"]` to `allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]`, see if it works then

Answer (score 0):

thanks it's work now but i need to go throw all the website news

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'example'
allowed_domains = ['www.Example.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.Example.com/1621305',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for article in response.css('.article'):
        yield {
        'title' : article.css('.article-title h1::text').extract(),
        'time'  : article.css('.article-time time::text').extract(),
        'article': article.css('.article-text p::text').extract(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did fix the code and it's work fine Yes Yes I did this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'example'
allowed_domains = ['www. example.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for article in response.css('.main-news'):
        yield {
        'title'     : article.css('.article-title h1::text').extract(),
        'time'      : article.css('.article-time time::text').extract(),
        'another'   : article.css('.article-source::text').extract(),
        'section'   : response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/ol/li[2]/a//text()').extract(),
        'article'   : article.css('.article-text p::text').extract() }


    for next_page in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```